# Most repeated string in pandas groupby aggregate fucntion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like this

| Customer ID | Amount | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2500 | India |
| 2 | 3000 | USA |
| 1 | 1000 | India |
| 2 | 500 | India |
| 1 | 2500 | India |
| 1 | 500 | USA |
| 2 | 500 | USA |

How can I use groupby aggregate function in pandas to return the sum of Amount column and most repeated string in Location column on customer level:

| Customer ID | Amount | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5500 | India |
| 2 | 400 | USA |

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with aggregate functions, for [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) is necessary add `iat[0]` for get first value if multiple top values:

```
df.groupby('Customer ID').agg({'Amount':'sum', 'Location': lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]})
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please share why would you use lambda with Location but not with the Amount column?

Comment: @MusaibJan - because `mode` is not implemented in `groupby.mode`

Comment: Thanks yet again. And what is the purpose of using .iat[0]?

Comment: @MusaibJan - if same number of top values `mode` return multiple values, so `iat[0]` return first vlue